# How does all() work on a boolean input, when the docs clearly mention the parameter should be an iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, range

I was working on this [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/monotonic-array/). I managed to solve it and later looked upon the solution to find this :-

```
class Solution(object):

## A is the Given Array
def isMonotonic(self, A): 
    return (all(A[i] <= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A) - 1)) or
            all(A[i] >= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A) - 1)))
```

My doubt is regarding the usage of all() in this manner - `all(A[i] <= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A) - 1))`, clearly all() is being called with a boolean parameter and it works. But when I executed `all(True)` in python console I got `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`. So basically how did the usage of all() in this manner work in the code but not in the console.

My another doubt is in `A[i] <= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A) - 1)`. When `i` reaches the last index value of the list shouldn't `A[i] <= A[i+1]` raise an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: Index out of range: the `range(len(A)-1)` ensures this doesn't happen.

Comment: Both of your doubts are wrong: it's an `iterable` of booleans (here a `generator`), which is the only argument `all` works with and the range is till `len(A) - 1`.

Comment: `A[i] <= A[i+1] for i in range(len(A) - 1)` is a generator - i..e returns a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [list comprehension.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)<sup>1</sup> In this instance, the input to `all()` is a list of booleans, which could be rewritten as a `for` loop like so:

```
bools = []
for i in range(len(A) - 1):
    bools.append(A[i] <= A[i + 1])
all(bools)
```

For your second doubt, we can look to the definition of the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) function (emphasis mine):

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and **r[i] < stop**.

Essentially, the `range` method is exclusive on the maximum, meaning the generator `range(len(A)-1)` will only go up to `len(A) - 2`.

1: Technically this isn't a list but a generator. The difference is that a generator only creates new values as needed, rather than all of them at the same time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/14336931) on the definition of `yield` for a more in-depth look.